# socket.io reconnect does not work as expected

Tags: socket.io

Whenever a player logouts in my game, the server disconnects the client; however, when the player tries to login again after already being disconnected, the client tries to renew the connection -- upon a successful reconnect, I execute a callback function. I do this by using the Socket.IO function

```
client.io.reconnect();
```

The server successfully shows that a new connection was made, but the client still seems to be totally disconnected. Why is this?

Summary: server disconnects client. I can't get client to successfully reconnect and fire the `client.on('connect')` event.

Comment: Are you also monitoring the reconnect event?

Comment: I think if you disconnect the client, then you should try to connect again, not reconnect :)

Comment: @Gary Looks like the reconnect event does fire successfully; however, anything I emit from the client is not picked up by the server. Although the server does alert me that the client has reconnected.

Comment: @AndreyPopov What do you mean? I would lose all my event listeners that way if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client side is made so if it's forced to disconnect, it cannot reconnect. You can see it in the code [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L357) and [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/manager.js#L500):

```
// socket.js
/**
 * Called upon forced client/server side disconnections,
 * this method ensures the manager stops tracking us and
 * that reconnections don't get triggered for this.
 *
 * @api private.
 */

// manager.js

Manager.prototype.reconnect = function(){
  if (this.reconnecting || this.skipReconnect) return this;
```

If you are afraid you will lose your listeners, then introduce a function to add those listeners and add them when needed :)